# calculate the number of heterozygotes

Tags: genetics, homework, hardy-weinberg

The ability to taste PTC is due to a single dominant allele "T". You sampled 215 evolution students, and determined that 150 could detect the bitter taste of PTC and 65 could not. Assuming this trait is in Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium in this population and that there are only two alleles, calculate the number of heterozygotes for this trait there are in the population.

Comment: How do I formulate this into hardy-weinberg eqbm form need help.

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Total  215  Calculations
Can taste PTC  150 
Cam't taste PTC  65 







For recessive  0.3023255814

Sqrt of recessive q  0.5498414148

p=1-q  0.4501585852

2pq  0.4950316667

Comment: Maybe just edit your question to add that information.

Comment: @krushna this site is not a homework answering service. I suggest you read this post about homework questions. http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/266/homework-policy-for-faq/267#267

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardy-Weinberg law gives the frequencies of genotypes from allele frequencies: $p^2 + 2pq + q^2$

Because the allele "T" is dominant, the frequency you're directly measuring through the experiment is the addition of $p^2$ and $2pq$.

$$p^2 + 2pq = 150/215 ≈ 0.6976$$

solving for $p$ (and replacing $q$ by $1-p$) gives:

$$p = 1 - \sqrt{\frac{13}{42}} ≈ 0.45 $$

The frequency of heterozygotes is given by:

$$2p(1-p) ≈ 0.4950 $$

And the number of heterozygotes in a population of 215 individuals is given by:

$$215 \cdot 0.4950 = 106.43$$

That sounds very alike what you wrote in the comments!

Comment: yeah I calculated the heterozygotes frequency but I was clueless how to find the number...of heterozygotes...but thanks for your help..